# Python let's me override operators in custom classes. But can I redefine how operators work with basic datatypes?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

Just to clarify, I can't imagine ever wanting to do this. But let's  say I want to modify how `==` works. Not in the context of a custom class I'm making, but in *all* cases. Let's say, for instance, that I want to redefine `==` so it ignores its operands and returns `True` in all cases.

So,

```
>>>> 1 == 5
True

>>>> True == False
True
```

Can this be done? My curiosity won't let me rest until I know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic types like `int` or `bool` are written as C extension types for which the methods can't be changed:

E.g. trying to make integer `+` subtracting:

```
>>> int.__add__ = int.__sub__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    int.__add__ = int.__sub__
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'int'
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty certain you can not overload operators of built in types. But I suppose you could wrap it

```
class MyInt(int):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other == 5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = MyInt(2)
    print(i == 5)
    i += 5
    print(i == 5)
    print(i)
```

The MyInt class would just act like an normal int but its equality check is overwritten and would return what ever you want it to. However as soon as you start using other operators it will return to being a normal int. You would have to overwrite all the operators as well, making sure you always return MyInt.

Output:

> True
>
> False
>
> 7

That's pretty much the only way I can think of achieving something close to what you asked for.